# Sorting thr first column in a matrix and returning the previous corresponding values of second column

Tags: matlab

I need to Sort the first column of the Job matrix and when giving back Job again return the corresponding values of the second column.
For example if

```
Job=[8 19;5 11;18 23;10 26]
```

I want this as result

```
Job=[5 11;8 19;10 26;18 23]
```

This is How I've wrote the starting steps

```
Pt=randint(10,1,[10,30])
d=randint(10,1,[5,20])
Job=[d,Pt]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I interpreted correctly your question. If I did, `sortrows` does the job:

```
  Job2 =   sortrows(Job)

 Job2 =

 5    11
 8    19
10    26
18    23
```

And to obtain the second column you type

```
   Job2(:,2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to matlab and seems that i don't know the easiest things,sorry about that

Comment: @SepidehGhajari You're welcome. No problem at all! We are all here to learn. Therefore, Welcome to Stackoverflow.